# Prevent translation files from being cleaned by Makefile

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, cmake

I am using `Qt Creator` 4.0.0 along with `CMake` > 3.4.

I am generating translation files thanks to this command:

```
QT5_CREATE_TRANSLATION(${PROJECT_NAME}_TRANSLATIONS_COMPILED ${${PROJECT_NAME}_TRANSLATIONS_SOURCES} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_TRANSLATIONS_FILES})
```

Each time I build my project, the translation files are either created or updated if they already exist.

However, when I clean the project, the `ts` files are removed. Is there an easy way from `CMake` or `Qt Creator`  to prevent them from being cleaned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way to prevent them from being cleaned is to simply put your `ts` files with your executable sources:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SOURCES} ${TS_FILES} ${QM_FILES})
```